# Solidity Vs JavaScript?

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, dapps, javascript, games

I'm currently in the process of writing a game however a question has popped up in my head.

A while back I started writing my game in Solidity (i.e the characters, names, stats etc.) and I had completely forgotten. I was just going to use JavaScript to manipulate how the site/game looks etc.

I recently found my old .sol files whilst I was just planning on how to write the game in javascript (i.e the same thing, characters, names, stats etc.) but then came up with the question on, is there really a difference between Solidity and Javascript on how the game will handle, so should I carry on writing as much as my game as possible in Solidity and for those bits I cannot do, write in Javascript.

Or should I just use Solidity to handle the backend of the game (for example, the process of managing money, rewards, payment etc.)?
Any ideas?
Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solidity can be used for blockchain based projects (or parts of projects) only.

The more rationale way is to handle offchain everything that can be handled off chain, possibly written in some language efficient for the off chain world (and JavaScript is primarily that), and to have on blockchain all what cannot be handled in a different way.

At that point Solidity is ok.

The union of the two languages each of them working where it can be stronger results in a very interesting general efficiency.

Doing something different is not reccomandable.

Comment: Thank you, I will use Javascript to create everything within the game, when it comes to sending transactions to the blockchain and making payments/receiving payments, I will write that in solidity.

Comment: You are welcome